# How to call correct method from massAction

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using an extension,  Blue Jalappeno Order Export for exporting orders, which works great. I modified one of the output format options to work for our fulfillment company and it is working well for us.

Now we need another export that uses a different format. I have the format fairly nailed down. 
My problem is with calling the new massAction in the order grid. 
This works to show the new action #2 in the pull down.

```
class Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
  protected function _prepareMassaction()
  {
    parent::_prepareMassaction();
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig("order_export/export_orders/active")) {

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('ordermanager', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Export orders IFS'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_export/csvexport'),
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getStoreConfig("order_export/export_orders2/active")) {

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('ordermanager2', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Export orders QB'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_export/qbexport'),
        ));
    }
  }
}
```

The first, working export still works. The second does show up and allows me to select and submit it but behaves differently. The url for the first never changed (/admin/sales_order/index) but the download box pops up. The url for the second changes to admin/sales_order_export/qbexport/  and presents a white screen

What I'd like it to do is call a different method in the same controller. Or pass a parameter to one method.

What I'm trying:
I added a method in the same controller used for the first addItem.

```
class Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Sales_Order_ExportController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function csvexportAction()  // First working mass action
{
$orders = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());

switch(Mage::getStoreConfig('order_export/export_orders/output_type')){
    case 'Multi':
    $file = Mage::getModel('webshopapps_ordermanager/export_multi')->exportOrders($orders);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($file, file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$file));
    break;

    case 'Standard':
    $file = Mage::getModel('webshopapps_ordermanager/export_csv')->exportOrders($orders);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($file, file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$file));
    break;

    }
}
public function qbexportAction()  
{
$orders = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
switch(Mage::getStoreConfig('order_export/export_orders/output_type2')){
    case 'Qb':
    $file = Mage::getModel('webshopapps_ordermanager/export_qb')->exportOrders($orders);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($file, file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$file));
    break;

    case 'Standard':
        $file = Mage::getModel('webshopapps_ordermanager/export_csv')->exportOrders($orders);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($file, file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$file));
    break;
    case 'Mscrm':
    $file = Mage::getModel('webshopapps_ordermanager/export_mscrm')->exportOrders($orders);
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($file, file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('export').'/'.$file)); 
    break;

    }
}
```

And the config.xml. I have looked and do not understand what makes the first massaction call the correct controller and action, but not the second. A glitch in my understanding that I need corrected.

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Webshopapps_Ordermanager>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Webshopapps_Ordermanager>
</modules>
 <global>
    <models>
        <webshopapps_ordermanager>
            <class>Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Model</class>
        </webshopapps_ordermanager>
    </models>
    <helpers>
    <webshopapps_ordermanager>
        <class>Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Helper</class>
    </webshopapps_ordermanager>
    </helpers>
     <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
<admin>
     <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Webshopapps_Ordermanager before="Mage_Adminhtml">Webshopapps_Ordermanager</Webshopapps_Ordermanager>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Webshopapps_Ordermanager>
                <files>
                    <default>Webshopapps_Ordermanager.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Webshopapps_Ordermanager>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <default>
    <ordermanager>
    <condition_name>order_export</condition_name>
    </ordermanager>
    </default>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <order_export>
                                        <title>Export Orders</title>
                                    </order_export>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: What is the controller's class name?

Comment: @pspahn Webshopapps_Ordermanager_Sales_Order_ExportController   I edited the code to add the controller name.  thanks

Comment: I'd like to know what in the config calls the controller with a different method but causes the download.

Comment: the config just sets up the controller in the `routers` section. The path is what controls which module/controller/action is called (with optional argument/parameter as additional path segments). See http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world for basics about how controllers work (this article goes over frontend, not admin stuff, but the basics still apply).

Comment: Thats just it, on the original mass action, the one I am copying,  the correct code is executed as indicated by the url in add mass action but just a download box pops up, the url didn't change.  I copied the first one but it functions differently. the url changed to the controller/method. I cannot tell what it is that forces the download box  to pop up.

Comment: OK this is calling the correct method and passing the parameter as required, the trouble was a typo in a parameter in the method.  So @pspahn answered the question correctly and pointed me to good info. thanks